# Извлечение данных JSON (string) в Python. Как сделать?

Tags: python, json

Я работаю в телеграмм-боте, но это не столь важно. Мне нужно знать, ведь при подобном коде:

```
TEXT_TO_TEXT_URL = "https://fasttranslator.herokuapp.com/api/v1/text/to/text"
LANG = "ru"
TEXT = message.text
url = f"{TEXT_TO_TEXT_URL}?source={TEXT}&lang={LANG}"
resp = requests.get(url)
```

message.text = это значение, которое ввел пользователь в сообщении
Например: Example for Stackoverflow
Мне выдает это:

`{"status":200,"message":"OK","mime_type":"text/plain","data":"Пример для Stackoverflow","lang":"en-ru","src_size":25}`

Как мне получить данные из data?

Comment: `import json` и затем почитайте, `json.loads( message.text )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скачиваем наш json

```
resp = requests.get(url).json()
```

и работаем как со словарем

```
print(resp["data"])
```

requests преобразует json в словарь без установки дополнительных библиотек